# Firebase fetching a child which contains a huge array

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

While firebase recommends use of indexes to keep the data structure flat, I am running into an issue here. 
Consider this users entity (from Firebase docs sample)

```
{
"users": {
  "mchen": {
    "name": "Mary Chen",
    // index Mary's groups in her profile
    "groups": {
       // the value here doesn't matter, just that the key exists
       "alpha": true,
       "charlie": true
       "delta" : true
       ...
       "10000th entry":true
    }
  },
  ...
}
```

Now I can read a user from the database like this.

```
List<User> users = new Select().from(User.class).limit(5).execute();
```

But, my question is if the `"groups"` key has say 10,000 entries what would happen? Will it fetch the whole list? Wouldn't it crash the app, due to lack of memory.

In general, if I am trying to fetch a high level node (which has nested nodes), what part of it will be fetched?

Comment: In Firebase you can select the number of items you want to fetch with a limitTo function and also give them priority to set an specific order, this would avoid that lack of memory like fetching the latest groups and limiting to the last 20 for example, you can do this with both value and child_added listeners...

Comment: Also if you fetch a high level node  with value all of it will be fetched and if you do it with child_added still all be fetched but not at once but in multiple parts..one for each child.... can you elaborate a little more your doubt???

Comment: `List<User> users = new Select().from(User.class).limit(5).execute();` What is this syntax?